# Appending NSString into left hand side in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, append

The following code is appending the `intString` into the right hand side of the `resultString`

```
resultString = [resultString stringByAppendingString:intString];
```

Is there any simple solution that I could append the `intString` on the left of the `resultString`

For example:

```
intString = "2";

resultString = "1";
```

Instead of giving the result of "12", I want the result of "21"

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just swap the argument and receiver:

```
resultString = [intString stringByAppendingString:resultString];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringWithFormat` method:

```
resultString  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", intString, resultString];
```